# Lisp loop do let when

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to do something like this

```
(loop for i from 1 to 10
      do (let ((fi (funcall f i)))
           when (> fi 0)
           collect (list i fi)))
```

f is expensive to compute, so I want to only calculate it once.

This isn't working, so I introduce my `fi` local variable outside the loop scope:

```
(let ((fi nil))
  (loop for i from 1 to 10
        do (setf fi (funcall f i))
        when (> fi 0)
        collect (list i fi)))
```

Is there a way to do this (like the first way) that is completely contained within the loop macro?

Comment: See how to compute intermediate variables: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html#computing-an-intermediate-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two independent `for` clauses will do:

```
(loop for i from 1 to 10
      for fi = (funcall f i)
      when (> fi 0)
      collect (list i fi))
```

Both iteration clauses will be executed at every iteration. The second one will see each new value of `i`.